# how to prevent default form submission on ajax call

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to disable the default form action while calling ajax. But currently with this below code its not happening.
Can anyone help me how to prevent default form action call when form is submitted.

```
//--------add project action ajax call start-------------  
$("#add_project_id").keypress(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (e.which == 13) { //pressed enter after endering in textbox  
        //--bootstrap validation----
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#add_project_id").validate({
            rules: {
                projectName: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            tooltip_options: {
                projectName: {
                    placement: 'left',
                    html: true
                }
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('#loadingimgid').css('display', 'block');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#project-formid').serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    alert("success");
                    $('#loadingimgid').css('display', 'none');
                }
            }); // <- end '.ajax()'

        }
        });
}
}); //]]>
```

Html form

```
 <form action="http://localhost/task/index.php/mypage" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="delete_existing_routine" id="project-formid">  
                  <input id="add_project_id" name="projectName" type="text" style="width: 70%;" required/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Start by opening your console and fix the syntax errors.

Comment: Looks like your code won't even work. You are trying to do `e.which == 13` but your event is called `event`, not `e`.

Comment: ^^^ And the `submithandler` is not part of the object passed to validate, you've closed that with one too many `},` so start indenting your code properly and you'll notice stuff like that.

Comment: @adeneo can you please update my code, where i am missing the syntax. I can see  `syntax error` on console. Please update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to bind `keypress` or `submit` event. Your Validate Submit handler automatically prevent form submission. [Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Like in this code if you use `form.submit()` from will submit

```
$(".selector").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do other things for a valid form
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

in following

```
$(".selector").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do other things for a valid form
    //ajax request 
  }
});
```

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/myn4K/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041732/jquery-submitting-nested-form-using-jquery-class-selector   plz help me

Comment: Click this link => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052213/how-to-submit-a-form-loaded-over-bootstrap-popover     . i have asked new question on this link