# submit a form which is loaded on bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

how to submit form loaded on the bootstrap popover?

On click on a button ,a form will be loaded on popover & the same form user should be able submit it by pressing ENTER key. [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aSZ6q/7/)

i tried like this but its loaded whole page

```
 $('#popoverId').popover({
        html: true,
        title: 'Popover Title<a class="close" href="#");">&times;</a>',
        content: $('#popoverContent').html(),
    });

    $('#popoverId').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
            $('#popoverId').popover('hide');
        }
    });


    //--------------script to to submit form after validation -------------

      $(".popover").parent().find('#something').validate({
                rules: {
                               sproject_name: {
                                   minlength: 3,
                                   maxlength: 15,
                                   required: true
                               }, tooltip_options: {
                                   sproject_name: {placement: 'center', html: true, trigger: 'focus'}
                               }
                           },
                          submitHandler: function(e) {console.log("ajax logi goes here...."); 
                                        }
                       });
```

**html code**

```
<h3>Live demo</h3>

<button id="popoverId" class="popoverThis btn btn-large btn-danger">Click to open form</button>

<div id="popoverContent" class="hide">
   <form method="post" name="project-forms" id="something"><input  class="red-tooltip" id="sadd_project_id" name="sproject_name" type="text" required/></form>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to use `.validate` inside popover click. See my answer for further detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.validate` inside `#popoverId` click. Because, you are using it on page load and at that time popover form still not exist. You can see following code and demo for bets understanding;

```
$('#popoverId').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#something').validate({
            rules: {
                sproject_name: {
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    required: true
                }
            },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: $(form).attr('method'),
                url: $(form).attr('action'),
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                dataType : 'json'
            })
            .done(function (response) {
                if (response.success == 'success') {               
                    alert('success');                       
                } else {
                    alert('fail');
                }
            });
        return false;  
        }
    });

});
```

See working demo here: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aSZ6q/15/)**

Comment: Thanks! can you able to help for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052213/how-to-submit-a-form-loaded-over-bootstrap-popover

Comment: If my answer fixed your case, you can approve this answer and I can help another question. Thanks

Comment: @Folks You can see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052213/how-to-submit-a-form-loaded-over-bootstrap-popover/23059442#23059442

Comment: You need to put submit button to form `<input type="submit" style="height:0;width:0;padding:0;border:0;margin:0;"/>` . See working example here http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/aSZ6q/13/

Comment: ok thats done! i have another issue On success i want to call submit this form using ajax & without loading the page, but currently its loading entire page...

Comment: I have updated my answer and demo. You can use this http://jsfiddle.net/aSZ6q/15/ . See console for ajax request